# is there another way to generate client with prisma-client-go?

Tags: go, prisma

i am setting  up a project in go and i  want to use the prisma-client-go as ORM tool.
i have setup  `schema.prisma` file like this

```
datasource db {
    // could be postgresql or mysql
    provider = "sqlite"
    url      = "file:dev.db"
}

generator db {
    provider = "go run github.com/prisma/prisma-client-go"
    // set the output folder and package name
    output           = "./db"
    package          = "db"
}

model Post {
    id        String   @default(cuid()) @id
    createdAt DateTime @default(now())
    updatedAt DateTime @updatedAt
    title     String
    published Boolean
    desc      String?
}
```

from the github docs, i have to run the generate command but when i run this

```
go run github.com/prisma/prisma-client-go migrate dev --name init
```

only a migration directory is outputted. no generated client  folder hence i cannot make use of the said schema... any pointers to what i'm  getting wrong? i have created a brand new project as well just to double check but i get the same behaviour

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The command auto-generates the client into the `./db` folder, in your case as well as you set it in the schema, but it's the same as the default.

```
❯ go run github.com/prisma/prisma-client-go migrate dev --name init
Prisma schema loaded from schema.prisma
Datasource "db": SQLite database "dev.db" at "file:dev.db"

SQLite database dev.db created at file:dev.db

Applying migration `20230526010255_init`

The following migration(s) have been created and applied from new schema changes:

migrations/
  └─ 20230526010255_init/
    └─ migration.sql

Your database is now in sync with your schema.

✔ Generated Prisma Client Go to ./db in 909ms
```

[image]

To just re-generate the client library, you can always just run `generate`:

```
go run github.com/prisma/prisma-client-go generate
```